# Extending auth_group_permission table in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I want to extend the **auth_group_permission** table. I know the table is made between many to many relationship with **auth_permission** table and **auth_group** table.

The **auth_group_permission** table contains **id**, **group_id** and **permission_id**. I want to make another table that will be one to one relationship with **auth_group_permission** table. So, i am finding it difficult to import the **auth_group_permission** table.

If anyone have any ideas or suggestions to how to achieve it, then it will be very helpful.

Comment: Hi @iamdanchiv. I have edited the query. Thanks for the suggestion and guidance.